# b-nav-form in bootstrap-vue example not rendering correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

The Navbar example in the documentation [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/navbar/) includes a `<b-nav-form>` section embedded within the navbar, containing a `<b-form-input>` and `<b-button>`.  But when I try to use that sample in my own page, only the input box is visible (it's on top of the button -- if I remove the `<b-form-input>`, I can see the button).  I have a jsfiddle example of the problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wcwb1q0z/12/).

Their example looks like this: [Expected Navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4bdd.png)

It ends up looking like this when I try to use it: [Resulting Navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syVJa.png)

Is this an issue with the version(s) of libraries/css I'm using? 
(Currently the latest of each: bootstrap 4.0.0, bootstrap-vue 2.0.0-rc.1, vue 2.5.13, and I've tried a few combinations of earlier ones.)  I can't tell which versions of libraries bootstrap-vue.js.org is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

`<b-nav-form>
    <b-form-input class="mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search"></b-form-input>
    <b-button class="my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</b-button>
</b-nav-form>`

Comment: Perhaps, you should consider adding a few line to highlight why your suggestion would work and/or where the differences with the original post are.

Comment: Interesting...  Changing `<b-form-input .../>` to `<b-form-input ...></b-form-input>` made it work.  (Ciradil's answer also removed the `size="sm"` attributes.  But it was the change to open/close tags instead of a self-closing tag that did it.)